# I'm looking for sth better than GDI+ for Delphi

Tags: delphi, graphics, gdi+

I'm looking for some unit or sth like GDI+ that doesn't need runtime libraries. I just need text and image effects.

Answer (score 9):

[GR32_lines and GR32_text](http://angusj.com/delphi/gr32_lines.php) by Angus based on [Graphics32](http://graphics32.org), plus [Clipper - native Delphi clipping lib](http://angusj.com/delphi/clipper.php) also by Angus. Both are free, open source and EXCELLENT! Angus is a good guy in the Delphi community.

Answer (score 7):

Take a look to [AggPas](http://www.crossgl.com/aggpas/) good for 2D drawing and antialiasing text

Comment: I'd be interested to hear some opinions, based on experience (!), as to which of Graphics32 and AggPas is faster for anti-aliased line drawing.

Comment: @David: It seems that Graphics32 is somewhat faster.

Answer (score 2):

[Graphics32](http://graphics32.org/) perhaps?

You will need to be a bit more specific, I'm afraid - the question is very vague.

Answer (score 1):

You could try [Graphics32](http://graphics32.org/wiki/). I've been very impressed with it for my needs.